# I'm developing an AJAX form that submits information to a database. It's logging an error when it reaches the insert function

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, post

I've put together an ajax style form that has a simple animated validation through jQuery. When everything checks out, it posts the content to my database. Or at least, that's the idea. Right now it logs an error at the very end of the function rather than inserting the information.

It consists of:

- `db.php`, connects to database
- `scripts.js` (+jQuery), form validation
- `index.php`, the form and such
- `insert.php`, inserts post data into the database

**db.php**

```
<?$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db_name","db_pass");
    if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
?>
```

**scripts.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

    // Tell console that it's started the validation
        console.log("Begin Validation");

    // Dump post data into variables
        var alert = false;
        var first = $("#firstname").val();
        var last = $("#lastname").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var phone = $("#phone").val();
        var dropdown = $("#dropdown").val();

    // Check first name field 
        if (first.length === 0) {
            var alert = true;
            $("#firstname").addClass("error");
        } else {
            $("#firstname").removeClass("error");
        }

    // Check last name field
        if (last.length === 0) {
            var alert = true;
            $("#lastname").addClass("error");
        } else {
            $("#lastname").removeClass("error");
        }

    // Check email field
        if (email.length < 7 || email.indexOf("@") == "-1" || email.indexOf("@.") != -1 || email.indexOf("-.") != -1 || email.indexOf("_.") != -1 || email.indexOf("..") != -1 || email.indexOf("._") != -1 || email.indexOf(".-") != -1 || email.indexOf(".@") != -1 || email.indexOf("@-") != -1 || email.indexOf("@_") != -1 || email.indexOf("@") == -1 || email.indexOf(".") == -1) {
            var alert = true;
            $("#email").addClass("error");
        } else {
            $("#email").removeClass("error");
        }

    // Check phone field
        if (phone.length === 0) {
            var alert = true;
            $("#phone").addClass("error");
        } else {
            $("#phone").removeClass("error");
        }

    // Check dropdown field
        if ($("#dropdown").val() === 0) {
            var alert = true;
            $("#dropdown").addClass("error");
        } else {
            $("#dropdown").removeClass("error");
        }

    // If anything returned an error, display the alert dialog
        if (alert === true) {
            $(".formcheck").slideDown(500);
        }

    // If no issues were found, disable submit button and proceed to data insertion
        if (alert === false) {
            $(".formcheck").slideUp(500);
            $("#submit").attr({
                disabled: "true",
                value: "Sending Info..."
            });

            console.log("Finish validation, move on to insert.php");

        // Insert the data into the database via php file, echo success message to form
            $.post("insert.php", $("#form").serialize(), function (e) {
                console.log("Post data to insert.php");
                if (e == "sent") {
                    console.log("Hide submit button and display success message");
                    $("#submit").slideUp(500);
                    $(".formfail").slideUp(500);
                    console.log("remove submit and errors");
                    $(".formsuccess").slideDown(500);
                    console.log("message sent successfully");
                } else {
                    console.log("something went wrong");
                    $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled").attr("value", "Submit");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**index.php**

```
<? include 'db.php'; ?>
<!doctype html>
  <head>
      <!-- meta info and such goes here -->

      <link rel='stylesheet' href='theme.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
      <script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action='#submit' method='post' id='form'>
    <div class='formsuccess'>Your entry has been submitted; Thank you.</div>
    <div class='formerror'>There was a problem submitting the entry.</div>
    <div class='formcheck'>Please check the form, something's missing.</div>
    <div class='formfail'>There was a problem contacting the server.</div>

    <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" tabindex="1" placeholder="First Name">
    <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" tabindex="2" placeholder="Last Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" tabindex="3" placeholder="Email">
    <input style="display:none" id="email2" name="email2" type="text">
    <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" tabindex="4" placeholder="Phone">

    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown" tabindex="5">
      <option value="0">Please select an option...</option>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>

    <input id="submit" name="submit" type="button" value="Submit"  tabindex="6"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?$con = mysql_connect("localhost","db_name","db_pass");
    if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}

mysql_select_db("db_name", $con);

//This bit makes the data input secure (preventing things like drop_tables, etc...)
function sanitize($input){
    switch(gettype($input)){
            case 'object':
            foreach($input as $key => $variable){
                            $input->$key = sanitize($variable);
                    }
            break;
            case 'array':
                    foreach($input as $key => $variable){
                            $input[$key] = sanitize($variable);
                    }
            break;
            case 'string':
                    //clean out extra sql queries
                    //remove poison null byte
                    //remove blank space at beginning and end of string
                    $input = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(htmlentities(str_replace(chr(0),'',$input),ENT_QUOTES)));
            break;
    }
    return $input;
}
//create an alias for "clean" version of our variable.
$post = sanitize($_POST);
//now use $post['firstname'] instead of $_POST['firstname'], $post has been cleaned.

//INSERT POST DATA INTO TABLES
$sql="INSERT INTO 'db_name'.'table_name' ('firstname', 'lastname', 'phone', 'email', 'dropdown')
    VALUES ('".$post['firstname']."','".$post['lastname']."','".$post['phone']."','".$post['email']."','".$post['dropdown']."')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }

echo 'sent';

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

That's all of it (of course, I stripped out branded bits). As it is now, it logs "something went wrong"

[image: something went wrong]

Which means it passes the JavaScript validation and successfully reaches the last function. unfortunately it isn't able to insert the information into the database and defaults to the else statement, which doesn't return the "sent" message to the script file -- thus no success.

I've been tinkering with this thing for hours and can't figure out why it's failing.

Comment: Have you tried alerting-out what you are getting back in your ajax success function? For example, after this line: `if (e == "sent") {` add: `alert(e);` and tell us what you see.

Comment: `console.log('Something went wrong: ' + e)`. might as well output what DID go wrong instead of just flailing around in the dark.

Comment: See the server response after posing to insert.php. It probably contain output of mysql_error() function. Or you have another characters in your response, newlines, spaces, not just `sent`.

Comment: Most likely `e` contains more than just `sent` or something other than `sent`.

Comment: Got it working!, two issues... 1. Insert Into 'db_name' wasn't correct. I had the db_user instead of the db_name there. After I corrected that, it dumped a new error: "Unknown column 'dropdown' in 'field list'"... PROGRESS!, dug into it and realized that I didn't make that column in the database after adding the field to the form. Added it, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use backticks, not quotes for table/column names.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `db_name`.`table_name` (`firstname`, `lastname`, `phone`, `email`, `dropdown`)
    VALUES ('".$post['firstname']."','".$post['lastname']."','".$post['phone']."','".$post['email']."','".$post['dropdown']."')"
```

Or none, just:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO table_name (firstname, lastname, phone, email, dropdown)
    VALUES ('".$post['firstname']."','".$post['lastname']."','".$post['phone']."','".$post['email']."','".$post['dropdown']."')"
```

I also would trash your `sanitize()` function  and all the `mysql_*` functions and revert to parametrized queries instead. Look into [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), something like:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:dbname=db_name;host=127.0.0.1;charset=utf8', 'db_name', 'db_pass');

$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO table (firstname, lastname, phone, email, dropdown) VALUES (:firstname, :lastname, :phone, :email, :dropdown)';
$stmt->execute(array('firstname' => $_POST['firstname'], 'lastname' => $_POST['lastname'],
'phone' => $_POST['phone'], 'email' => $_POST['email'], 'dropdown' => $_POST['dropdown']));
```

Comment: Turns out my issue was having the db_user instead of the db_name in that sql INSERT script. I've updated that and it's working fine. I also took your advice and removed the excess backticks. I'm not familiar with PDO, but I'll be sure to give it a try. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

mysql_real_escape_string is not a good way to escape data instead you should use PDO, prepared statements. In PDO you do not have to escape data. PDO will take care of it. Use bindParam to insert parameterized data in db.